# Can I make a cheese sauce with edam cheese?

Tags: cheese

I love the taste if edam cheese and I want to know if I can make a sauce with it? Like the sauce with the roux+milk+cheddar can I replace cheddar with edam?

Comment: I have made cheese sauce with Edam - and didn't like it!  :)  For that matter, I'd never use cheddar either!   But yes you absolutely "can do this" - give it a go.  As always make the roux extremely slowly and with great care.  There's nothing more difficult to make than roux.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, you should be OK.

It is a hard cheese, similar but different than cheddar, but should work.

You might have to experiment a little bit, even if the cheeses are similar, their behavior when melting might be different.